TargetInvocationException Thrown when Attempting to Load Text File in Android App
I'm writing a .NET MAUI app that loads Bible verses from a text file. Works fine when running on Windows, but the text file doesn't appear when running the app in the Android Emulator, even though I have the text file's Copy to output directory option set to Copy always. Instead, once the build finishes I get a TargetInvocationException because the file doesn't appear in the App Data Directory. How do I make sure the file is in the right place when running the app on Android?
I have this piece of code for loading the file:
                    string filePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory, "erv.txt");

                    Console.WriteLine(filePath);
                    if (!File.Exists(filePath)) {
                        throw new FileNotFoundException("erv.txt not found", filePath);
                    }

                    using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(filePath))


I tried adding this piece of code to the project file
    <Content Include="Resources\erv.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>


But it seems to make no difference.

use FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync

Thanks! I'll go about reworking my code to use this

Well, as an answer, you can refer to this official doc: File system helpers and use FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync method:
Add the file(erv.txt) into Resources\Raw folder and then set Build Action of it to MauiAsset. Finally, use the following code:
using var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("erv.txt");
using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
 
var contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(contents);


Tried setting the build action to MauiAsset, and using OpenAppPackageFileAsync, I'm still getting the TargetInvocationException. I'm trying to copy the file to the AppDataDirectory, using a code snippet taken from the documentation, but it doesn't seem to work. When I try to open the file after supposedly coppying it, I get an exception

Try to create a new project and then use OpenAppPackageFileAsync again?

Tried that. Didn't work.
